# Catch-all Servlet Preventing Resources From Loading

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am using a catch all servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name="RequestHandler", urlPatterns="/*")
public class RequestHandler extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    new SeedPlanter(request, response).sow();   
}

}
```

To handle all requests. Notice the `urlPattern` `/`*. The reason for this is because it loads a variety of things like templating, handling objects etc. The servlet is basically just a facade that sits in front of a custom framework that handles all of the html rendering.

The problem is I can no longer access resources directly.

For instance if I want to load an html file that is outside of the web-inf directory (`localhost:8080/myapp/test.html`) it gives me a 404 error. In fact, even when I attempt to load an image (`localhost:8080/myapp/images/test.png`) on a page it gives a 404 resource not found. Removing the servlet obviously ruins the entire application but it does allow me to load those resources so i'm confident its the servlet causing the problem.

How can I use the servlet like I am but also be able to load those resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a separate servlet that listens to my images, css, js folders (you could add as many urlPatterns as you'd like here).

```
@WebServlet(name="CommonRequestHandler", urlPatterns={"/images/*", "/css/*"})
public class CommonRequestHandler extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length()+1, request.getRequestURI().length());
    String fileName = context.getRealPath(path);

    //Get MIME type
    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
    if(mimeType == null) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return;
    }

    //Set content type
    response.setContentType(mimeType);

    //Set content size
    File file = new File(fileName);
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

    //Open file and output streams
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    //Copy file content to output stream
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    while((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
}
```

The code simply find the file and returns the bytes back to the browser.

Reference: http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/09/webxml-problem-and-solution-for-url.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Servlet **Filters** in this case, not the Servlets. Servlet filter is a way to add any code around request flow. There are plenty of examples on the Internet, here is [one of them](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/how-to-write-a-simple-servlet-filter/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to create/use a servlet filters to rewrite the paths correctly. [There's a good example of one here complete with source code](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) that looks like it might be helpful.

I've included the following for reference since often the actual functionality of the descriptors get mis-interpreted of how they should actually be implemented.

SRV.11.2 Specification of Mappings

In theWeb application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:

- A string beginning with a / character and ending with a /* suffix is
  used for path mapping.
- A string beginning with a *. prefix is used as an extension mapping.
- A string containing only the / character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
  request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.

All other strings are used for exact matches only.